# laravel 4 url redirect cache

Tags: laravel, caching, redirect

In my app, Home is the default Controller set.
I am having a Main controller which redirects to home page if a particular session variable is not set.
After Login validation, session is created for the user and redirects me to home page. On home page when I click on the link to main page "http://domain/main" it redirects the user to home page again.
when i type "http://domain/main/" in the url, it opens the right page. but "http://domain/main" is redirecting to "http://domain/home".
when i clear session files in storage and login "http://domain/main" works but after some time it redirects me to home page again.
I believe there is issue with laravel caching as in my code the redirection handling is perfect.

Comment: index.php is in public dir. home.php and main.php are in app/cotrollers. in main.php, it is written that if (Session::get("preferred_app_id") == "") {
            Redirect::to("home");
        }. at 1st preff_app_id is null but it is set on home page if user clicks on select of appid. but in browser or i dont know where it is cached that whenever reqst comes for /main it redirects to /home. but /main/ is working fine.

Comment: if(Session::has('preferred_app_id')){
//Do whatever you like
}else{
//redirect to home
}

In home:

if(Session::has('preferred_app_id')){
//Redirect to main
}

Comment: I think I just found the trick. this redirection is a browser cache. when I open my debugger in chrome and select diable cache button, everything works fine. there is nothing wrong with code.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes browser caches the redirect 301 url. So in your code if you set session variable on some condition. and you redirect(301) to a page on set of a session variable than your browser caches that redirection.
So if at first session variable is not set, and your code redirects(301) to a different link. next time when you set variable on client interaction and your session variable is set, even than your browser will redirect you to the cached link. to avoid that you must pass redirect http code to the redirectto('location url','302') function  in laravel.